# R rescale 2nd Y-axis according to a variable

Tags: r, yaxis, rescale

I have been trying to get a histogram and a line graph into one graph. The histogram is for exact amount of an antibiotic prescription (left y-axis). The line graph is the percentage of how much that antibiotic is used (right axis). So far, I have merged them together, moved the right axis to the right, but the right y-axis uses the same scale as the left. The scales of the histogram and the line graph are of course very very different.

Some information before my question starts:

- dataframe name = Grafiek3
- n_fosfo = the amount of perscriptions (used
  for the left y-axis)
- Jaren = years, the amount and percentage are
  visible per year (used for the x-axis)
- per_fos = percentage (used for
  the right y-axis), goes to approximately 11%

The code that I have now is:

```
  ggplot(Grafiek3, aes(x = Jaren, y =n_fosfo)) + #samenvoegen
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#69b3a2" ) +
scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(Grafiek3$Jaren), breaks = Grafiek3$Jaren) +
xlab ("Year") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle("Increase fosfomycin prescriptions per year")+
geom_line(aes(x=Jaren, y=per_fos), color="black") +
geom_point(aes(x=Jaren, y=per_fos), shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=2) +
scale_y_continuous(
  name = expression("Total amount of prescriptions"), 
  sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Percentage")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle("Percentage of fosfomycin prescriptions per year")
```

Output is as follows:
[Unfinished graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42JoQ.png)

As is seen, the line graph sits at the bottom, but should look something like this:

```
  ggplot(Grafiek3, aes(x=Jaren, y =per_fos)) + #line graph
  geom_line(color="grey") +
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=2) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(Grafiek3$Jaren), breaks = Grafiek3$Jaren) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  xlab ("Year") +
  ylab ("Percentage") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Percentage of fosfomycin prescriptions per year")
```

Picture:
[Line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NEzu.png)

I have seen that changing the code:

```
sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Percentage"))
```

into something like this:

```
sec.axis = sec_axis(~./42, name = "Percentage"))
```

Will fix it, but unfortunately that changes only the right axis, but the line graph doesn't move with it.

So, does anybody have an idea how I can move the line graph (picture) into the histogram? Or how to change the right axis so that it uses the information of the "per_fos" variable?

Made up dataset that can be of use:

```
years <- c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
amount <- c(120, 150, 200, 170, 180, 240, 80)
percentage <- c(5.4, 5.9, 6.3, 7.1, 7.8, 8.4, 10.4)
df <- data.frame(years, amount, percentage)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the real dataset due to privacy reasons. I will try to set up a "made up" dataset. 
The expected answer is already presented in the form of the 2 pictures I have provided as well as a description of how it should be. A real picture of the expected answer is of course not possible, otherwise I would ask my question.
The codes I have used are presented as well.

Comment: That would be great, it is often better to use a simplified set of data to work on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for improving my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know that two y-axis with different scales is not considered good practice. This is why it is not easy to do what you are trying to do with ggplot2. 
See this link for a good discussion on the issue:  [ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)


years <- c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
amount <- c(120, 150, 200, 170, 180, 240, 80)
percentage <- c(5.4, 5.9, 6.3, 7.1, 7.8, 8.4, 10.4)

df <- data.frame(years, amount, percentage)
# create a modified percentage column to fit in with the scale of the columns:

df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(pc_rescale = rescale(percentage, to = c(20, 200)))

# plot and add suitable labels; if you want the labels scaled evenly you need to unpick the rescaling function. 

ggplot(df, aes(years, amount)) +
  geom_col()+
  geom_line(aes(years, pc_rescale))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., labels = df$percentage, breaks = df$pc_rescale, name = "Percentage" ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This has helped me a lot! Now I can finish the graph to the corresponding needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the right axis with the right scales.

changing this code:
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., labels = df$percentage, breaks = df$pc_rescale, name = "Percentage" ))

To: scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~/40., name = "Percentage" ))
gives the wrong proportions as well.

How can I have the same scale as in my line graph picture? But with the numbers 4 to 11 in it?
So, the bottom starts at 4 instead of 0.

Comment: Nevermind, I have fixed it by changing numbers of the rescales and changing the breaks and labels.

Comment: That's right. If this answers your question it is customary to click the accept it : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers